# cut fragment of mp3 from, to and apply fade in, fade out

Tags: javascript, ffmpeg, web-audio-api

I am in need of a tool that will complete following tasks

1. provide `source` mp3
2. provide `data` of fragment to cut (`start` time, `end` time)
3. start cutting from `source` where `start` is
4. end cutting from `source` where `end` is
5. apply `X` seconds `fade in` beginning of `start` time
6. apply `Y` seconds `fade out` beginning `Y` seconds subtracted from `end`

By `fade` i mean `increase` / `decrease` volume between `0 - 100%` / `100% - 0`

I already have an interface that allows to prepare `data`.

On the backend side, I am working with `node.js`.

After some research i found a tool [FFmpeg](https://www.ffmpeg.org/) that was widely recommended to achieve my goal.

After further research i came up with following code:

```
const { stdout, stderr } = await exec('ffmpeg -y -i "' + sourcePath + '" -ss ' + start + ' -to ' + end + ' -af "afade=in:st=' + start + ':d=' + fadeLength + ',afade=out:st=' + (end - 3) + ':d=' + fadeLength + '" "' + outputPath + '"');

/*
Breakdown:
    ffmpeg
        -y
        -i "sourcePath"
        -ss start
        -to end
        -af "afade=in:st=(start):d=(fadeLength),afade=out:st=(end - fadeLength):d=3"
        "outputPath"

Example:
    ffmpeg
        -y
        -i "/source/test.mp3"
        -ss 89.382716
        -to 172.817231
        -af "afade=in:st=89.382716:d=5,afade=out:st=(172.817231 - 5):d=5"
        "/output/test_cut.mp3"
*/
```

It's working, but processor throws warnings:

```
[mp3 @ 0x7fc50a80c800] Estimating duration from bitrate, this may be inaccurate
[swscaler @ 0x114800000] deprecated pixel format used, make sure you did set range correctly
[mp3 @ 0x7fc50a819a00] Frame rate very high for a muxer not efficiently supporting it.
Please consider specifying a lower framerate, a different muxer or -vsync 2
```

Full log:

```
ffmpeg version 4.4 Copyright (c) 2000-2021 the FFmpeg developers
    built with Apple clang version 12.0.0 (clang-1200.0.32.29)
    configuration: --prefix=/usr/local/Cellar/ffmpeg/4.4_2 --enable-shared --enable-pthreads --enable-version3 --cc=clang --host-cflags= --host-ldflags= --enable-ffplay --enable-gnutls --enable-gpl --enable-libaom --enable-libbluray --enable-libdav1d --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopus --enable-librav1e --enable-librubberband --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsrt --enable-libtesseract --enable-libtheora --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwebp --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxml2 --enable-libxvid --enable-lzma --enable-libfontconfig --enable-libfreetype --enable-frei0r --enable-libass --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libspeex --enable-libsoxr --enable-libzmq --enable-libzimg --disable-libjack --disable-indev=jack --enable-avresample --enable-videotoolbox
    libavutil      56. 70.100 / 56. 70.100
    libavcodec     58.134.100 / 58.134.100
    libavformat    58. 76.100 / 58. 76.100
    libavdevice    58. 13.100 / 58. 13.100
    libavfilter     7.110.100 /  7.110.100
    libavresample   4.  0.  0 /  4.  0.  0
    libswscale      5.  9.100 /  5.  9.100
    libswresample   3.  9.100 /  3.  9.100
    libpostproc    55.  9.100 / 55.  9.100
[mp3 @ 0x7fc50a80c800] Estimating duration from bitrate, this may be inaccurate
Input #0, mp3, from 'test.mp3':
    Metadata:
        title           : Test
        artist          : Test
    Duration: 00:03:22.50, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 320 kb/s
    Stream #0:0: Audio: mp3, 44100 Hz, stereo, fltp, 320 kb/s
    Stream #0:1: Video: mjpeg (Baseline), yuvj420p(pc, bt470bg/unknown/unknown), 320x240, 90k tbr, 90k tbn, 90k tbc (attached pic)
        Metadata:
            comment         : Other
Stream mapping:
    Stream #0:1 -> #0:0 (mjpeg (native) -> png (native))
    Stream #0:0 -> #0:1 (mp3 (mp3float) -> mp3 (libmp3lame))
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
[swscaler @ 0x114800000] deprecated pixel format used, make sure you did set range correctly
[mp3 @ 0x7fc50a819a00] Frame rate very high for a muxer not efficiently supporting it.
Please consider specifying a lower framerate, a different muxer or -vsync 2
Output #0, mp3, to 'test (CUT).mp3':
    Metadata:
        TIT2            : Test
        TPE1            : Test
        TSSE            : Lavf58.76.100
    Stream #0:0: Video: png, rgb24, 320x240, q=2-31, 200 kb/s, 90k fps, 90k tbn (attached pic)
        Metadata:
            comment         : Other
            encoder         : Lavc58.134.100 png
    Stream #0:1: Audio: mp3, 44100 Hz, stereo, fltp
        Metadata:
            encoder         : Lavc58.134.100 libmp3lame
frame=    0 fps=0.0 q=0.0 size=       0kB time=00:00:39.89 bitrate=   0.0kbits/s speed=31.4x    
[mp3 @ 0x7fc50a819a00] No packets were sent for some of the attached pictures.
frame=    0 fps=0.0 q=0.0 Lsize=     626kB time=00:00:40.02 bitrate= 128.2kbits/s speed=31.4x    
video:0kB audio:626kB subtitle:0kB other streams:0kB global headers:0kB muxing overhead: 0.053810%
```

So my question is, how to change execution command to have it executed properly (avoid warnings and errors)?

Important thing is that i am only interested in cutting it, if possible avoid re-encondig because i am already working with 320 mp3's that have been produced from master wav's.

Answer (score 0):

If you're willing to use a browser for this, the following bit of code will do what you want.  (Untested though):

```
// Let sampleRate be the sample rate of the mp3 file.
// c is an AudioContext just so we can use decodeAudioData
let c = new AudioContext({sampleRate: sampleRate});
let buffer = await fetch('path-to-file')
                     .then(response => response.arrayBuffer)
             .then(buffer => c.decodeAudioData(buffer));

let oac = new OfflineAudioContext({
  numberOfChannels: buffer.numberOfChannels,
  sampleRate: buffer.sampleRate,
  length: buffer.length});

let src = new AudioBufferSourceNode(oac, {buffer: buffer});
// This will provide the fade in/out.
let gain = new GainNode(oac);

src.connect(gain);

// Set up fade in/out.  Fade in ends at time fadeInEndTime.  The fade
// out starts at time fadeOutBeginTime and ends at fadeOutEndTime.
gain.gain.setValueAtTime(0, 0);
gain.gain.linearRampToValueAtTime(1, fadeInEndTime);
gain.gain.setValueAtTime(1, fadeOutBeginTime);
gain.gain.linearRampToValueAtTime(0, fadeOutEndTime);

// Play the buffer now but use the samples at startTime in the buffer.
src.start(0, startTime, endTime - startTime);

// The result AudioBuffer will be an AudioBuffer containing the
// original MP3 file segment with the fade in/out applied.
let result = await oac.startRendering();
```

If you need to save the result back to an MP3 file, then you'll have
to do that yourself.  One way is to replace the OfflineAudioContext
with an AudioContext and use a MediaRecorder to do that.  Another way
is to use the resulting AudioBuffer and use (the new) WebCodecs API to
save it.

Comment: the only problem is that i am already using `wavesurfer.js` as interface so i have no idea how to combine it

Comment: I'm not familiar with wavesurfer.js, so I can't help with that.

Comment: that said, thanks to you i already managed to make fading and cutting directly to source, so that would be AudioBuffer, so i have access to already modified audio buffer, could you show, how to save mp3 from that audio buffer

Comment: Look into [MediaRecorder](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaRecorder); I'm not that familiar with it, having used it just once or twice, and mostly figured it out by googling for MediaRecorder examples.  There's also the new [WebCodecs API](https://www.w3.org/TR/webcodecs/) but I know even less about how to use that.